# No osx files in cordova-plugin-statusbar/networkstatus/network-information

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cordova, nwjs

I cloned the copay project for my development (https://github.com/Bitcoin-com/Wallet). There are dependencies involving statusbar and networkstatus, none for which the .m & .h files have been provided for OSX platform, in the cordova-plugin-statusbar and cordova-plugin-networkstatus (or the new cordova-plugin-network-information).
There are provisions only for android, iOS, windows, browser & wp. No OSX. The new cordova-plugin-network-information also includes (Blackberry10, firefoxos, tizen & ubuntu). Still no osx.

How can I work around this to be able to deploy to the osx platform?

**THE UNDERLYING PROBLEM** - For better understanding

After building copay and running the following command: $ cordova emulate osx, it builds OK and launches the OSX simulator with a blank screen. The other platforms (iOS and android) build and run OK, displaying the copay wallet app.
When i open the osx/Copay.xcodeproj file in Xcode, I run the app and it produces the same blank simulator screen. The error in the log reads:

```
2017-10-12 01:46:25.149 Copay[18616:649515] ERROR: Plugin 'NetworkStatus' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2017-10-12 01:46:25.149 Copay[18616:649515] ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
2017-10-12 01:46:30.027 Copay[18616:649515] deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
2017-10-12 01:46:30.027 Copay[18616:649515] Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
```

Apparently, the plugins not loading is preventing the cordova "onCordovaConnectionReady" event from firing. So, what is the way around this?
If i am wrong, please point me in the right direction.

See attached images.
Thanks

[image: Xcode error and failure to run]

[image: shows "installing cordova-pluging-statusbar for osx", but does not exist in osx plugin folder]

Comment: do you have any solution for this problem? please :)